# CakePHP não mostra caracteres especiais presentes no conteúdo da base de dados

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Eu obtenho algo como:

```
Produ��es - Casamento Catarina & Lu�s _ Caves Taylor�s
```

Mas o esperado era obter :

```
Produções - Casamento Catarina & Luís _ Caves Taylor's
```

Isto apenas acontece com dados provenientes da base de dados, que se encontram correctamente dentro da tabela com estes caracteres. A base de dados está configurada como `utf8_unicode_ci`, assim como as tabelas e os seus campos, e o servidor UTF-8 Unicode, assim como o CakePHP. Como se resolve isto?

Comment: Tem a tag `meta` definindo o charset no HTML (`<meta charset="utf-8">`)?

Comment: Sim tem essa tag inserida.

Comment: O encoding da conexão está definido no database.php do cake?

Comment: Não, e após retirar o comentário já funciona. Responda por favor para lhe dar a resposta certa sff. Obrigado.

Comment: Fiz isso. Uma dica: ao se dirigir a algum usuário que já comentou, inclua `@username_da_pessoa` no comentário, e ele será notificado.

Comment: Ok peço desculpa, esqueço-me sempre disso.

Comment: Sem problemas! É que se deixar de fazer isso, a pessoa pode nunca ver seu comentário (eu quase deixei passar esse pra mim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na configuração do banco que fica em `app/Config/database.php`, você precisa definir o *encoding* da conexão. No caso da configuração de exemplo do Cake para o MySQL, é só descomentar a linha comentada:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
        // Descomente a linha acima
    );
}
```